# Loop through visible input elements in a form in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, children

I'm trying to loop through all visible inputs within a form and set their value to be empty. What I have doesn't seem to work for text inputs, it returns undefined. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: what is `$(this)` referring to? And can you post your HTML so we can see the structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has a `:visible` selector as well as an `:input` selector. In addition, most jQuery methods operate on the entire set. `val()` can be used directly rather than looping through the set.

```
currentForm.find(':input:visible').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Textbox inputs would have a tagName of "textarea". Not sure why the other text types aren't working. Have you tried:

childs[i].values = '';

?